# How to add a background image

Tags: xcode, swift, background

I have a Image View on my storyboard, and when I am trying to use it as a background. No matter what I do, it always stays on top. How would I change it so that it would be a background image, I don't care weather I do it programmatically  through swift or through another way.

Comment: Just make sure that the imageView is the [first view under your controller's view](http://d.pr/i/WIsc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving any of item up/down you can set their layer state. The first one will be on back then second will appear on the first one then.... last one will appear on top most.

I hope this will help you.

[image: By moving any of item up/down you can set their layer state]

Answer (score 2):

In the Xcode Interface Builder, you can adjust which views are in the front by selecting the view and going to `Editor -> Arrange -> Send to Front, Back, etc.`

This can also be done programmatically using `UIView` methods like `bringSubviewToFront:`

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to do it programmatically, you can modify the `zPosition` property of the view:

```
myImageView.layer.zPosition = 1
```

Higher numbers are closer to your face, lower numbers are closer to the screen. So to set your image view as a background, make sure the other views have higher z-positions than it.