# self.view.insertSubview background image array not advancing

Tags: ios, arrays, uiimage, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I have my background image set by `self.view.insertSubview`. I'm trying to create a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` that advances through the background Image on swipe, while another image array cycles on tap. The tap image works fine but the swipe image only works on the first swipe.

Here's the gesture recognizer:

```
   let gestureRecognizerBackground = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changeBackground))
        dragon2View.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizerBackground)
```

and here's the `changeBackground` func:

```
func changeBackground() {

         let backgroundImageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "artic.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "beach.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "mountain.jpg"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "spring.png")]
        let randomBackground = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32 (backgroundImageArray.count)))

        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        backgroundImage.image = backgroundImageArray[randomBackground]
        self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)  

    }
```

Not sure why it's not advancing. Thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set the background image with self.view.insertSubview because I didn't realize I could just have two views and '[send to back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33372906/5992256)'. No problem with the array now.